# Iterating over files, save the last line of the file and the filename on a text file via STDOUT and pipe

Tags: bash, shell, awk

yesterday I asked the question how save the console output in a file (see [redirect only last line of STDOUT to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821731/redirect-only-last-line-of-stdout-to-a-file)). Now I iterate over files, compile them. Here is my command:

```
for REPORT in Test_Basic_*.scala; do
    scalac -Xplugin:divbyzero.jar $REPORT | awk 'END{print $REPORT} END{print}' >> output.txt
done
```

I want to save the last output of the compilation and the name of the file. In the example above only $REPORT will be saved but I want to refere to the name of the iteration variable.

For example I have the file Test_Condition.scala and run the command above:

```
for REPORT in Test_Basic_*.scala; do
    scalac -Xplugin:divbyzero.jar $REPORT | awk 'END{print $REPORT} END{print}' >> output.txt;
done
```

Then `scalac -Xplugin:divbyzero.jar $REPORT` produce the following output:

```
You have overwritten the standard meaning
Literal:()
rhs type: Int(1)
Constant Type: Constant(1)
We have a literal constant
List(localhost.Low)
Constant Type: Constant(1)
Literal:1
rhs type: Int(2)
Constant Type: Constant(2)
We have a literal constant
List(localhost.High)
Constant Type: Constant(2)
Literal:2
rhs type: Boolean(true)
Constant Type: Constant(true)
We have a literal constant
List(localhost.High)
Constant Type: Constant(true)
Literal:true
LEVEL: H
LEVEL: H
okay
LEVEL: H
okay
false
symboltable: Map(a -> 219 | Int | object TestIfConditionWithElseAccept2 | normalTermination | L, c -> 221 | Boolean | object TestIfConditionWithElseAccept2 | normalTermination | H, b -> 220 | Int | object TestIfConditionWithElseAccept2 | normalTermination | H)
pc: Set(L, H)
```

Now I want to save in output.txt `Test_Condition.scala` (name of the file) and `pc: Set(L, H)` (so the last line of the compilation output). With my command above I only save `$REPORT pc: Set(L, H)`.

If this explanation is to complicated just tell me. Thanks for your great support.

Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly, you simply want a way to execute a command on a bunch of files and then store both the name of the file and the last line of the output of the command.  This should work:

```
: > output # clear out the output file
for file in Test_Basic_*.scala; do
  printf "$file: " >> output
  scalac ... | awk 'END { print }' >> output
done
```

Comment: Exactly what I want, thousand thanks William you saved me the day and I learned the 'printf' command.

Comment: You can move the redirection to the end and you won't have to clear the file first: `for ... done > output`

Answer (score 2):

You only get the literal "$REPORT" because your awk script is enclosed in single quotes, which prevents the shell's substitution of the `REPORT` variable.

Try this:

```
scalac ... "$REPORT" | awk -v filename="$REPORT" 'END {print filename; print}' >> output
```

The `-v` option sets an awk variable named `filename` to hold the value of the shell's `REPORT` variable.

Also, it's a good rule of thumb to always quote shell variables (unless you specifically want the side effects of omitting them).

Comment: Another option would be to use the `ENVIRON` awk variable.  `... | awk 'END { print ENVIRON["SHELL"]; print }'`

Comment: @jamessan, yes but you'd have to export the variable first.